# Problema con route resource

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Tengo la siguiente estructura en las rutas:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ventas', 'as' => 'ventas.'], function () {
    //INICIO
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Inicio'], function() {
        Route::get('inicio', [
            'as' => 'inicio',
            'uses' => 'InicioController@index'
        ]);
    });
});
```

y en la vista llamo a esta ruta asi: `href="{{route('ventas.inicio')}}"`

Ahora si quiero agregar el Route::resource en vez de la anterior, esa misma ruta no me anda.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ventas', 'as' => 'ventas.'], function () {
    //INICIO
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Inicio'], function() {
         Route::resource('inicio', 'InicioController');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola @Juan Pablo en el resource no necesitas agregar un alias con '.'
pues es esto lo que te debe estar generando una ruta asi 'ventas.ventas.index', remueve ese alias y funcionara a la perfección
adjunto una imagen con las lista de rutas que me generó al hacer el ejercicio, espero te sirva, saludos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6):

Cuando usas resouce laravel que crea las rutas necesarias para realizar un CRUD

```
Route::resource('inicio','InicioController');
```

Las rutas generadas serían:

- inicio.create
- inicio.destroy
- inicio.show
- inicio.update
- inicio.edit

pero si quieres generar otra ruta con un alias sería:

```
Route::get('inicio',[
    'uses' => 'InicioController@index',
    'as'   => 'inicio'
]);
```

Comment: Puedes verificar las rutas existentes con el comando:
`php artisan route:list`